# How does the core.async >! function verify if its being called from inside of a go block

Tags: clojure, core.async

In core.async, if you call the `>!` function outside of a go block, it throws error saying `<! used not in (go ...) block`. How does the function know that its not being executed inside of a go block? I need to create something very similar where I need to ensure that a function can only be called from inside of a macro. How can I approach that? I've looked at the core.async source but I couldn't really figure out how it worked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the source code for `<!`:

```
(defn <!
  "Takes a value from the channel. Must be called inside a (go ...) block. Will
  return nil if closed. Will park if nothing is available."
  [port]
  (assert nil "<! used not in (go ...) block"))
```

Note that `assert` will throw an exception for any falsey value, so you get this error message if you use `<!` outside of a `go` block.

When you use the `go` macro, it recursively walks all of the code expressions it encloses, ***replacing*** symbols like `<!` with ***other code*** that does not call the "error case" code shown above.

Comment: sweet. thanks. I'm going to try to build something similar.

Answer (score 0):

Addition to Alan Thompson's answer here is the code(`go` macro) that **replacing symbols** like `<!` with other code that does not call the *error case*:

Also `[clojure.core.async.impl.ioc-macros :as ioc]` namespace used for this purpose.

```
   (dispatch/run
     (^:once fn* []
      (let [~@(mapcat (fn [[l sym]] [sym `(^:once fn* [] ~(vary-meta l dissoc :tag))]) crossing-env)
            f# ~(ioc/state-machine `(do ~@body) 1 [crossing-env &env] ioc/async-custom-terminators)
            state# (-> (f#)
                       (ioc/aset-all! ioc/USER-START-IDX c#
                                      ioc/BINDINGS-IDX captured-bindings#))]
        (ioc/run-state-machine-wrapped state#))))
```